# AngularJS - accessing elements inside a controller from a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app with two controllers where I want a change in one controller to affect (different) data stored in the other. tl;dr when I remove a category from the first controller, I want to edit any items in the second controller with that category, so that they will now be category-less.

As far as I can tell what I want is to use a service, but I feel it would be simpler if there were a way for me to simply edit the data inside the controller scope. So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to simply edit controller data or call controller methods from a service?
2. Otherwise, is it reasonable to store the latter controller's data in the service, even though the former controller only needs access to change it? How do I reference this data for the purpose of doing ng-repeats?

Edit: to clarify the data is a set of json objects which contain data for each category and each item, and the web page contains ng-repeats to go through and list each of them. I have a number of functions which edit both lists of data, and I want changes to one list to make changes in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea was correct, you should put all your business logic, including data that needs to be consistent between different parts of your application, into `services`. `controller`s should only manage the view and connect the data to it.

Keep in mind that `service`s are [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)s - there is always only one instance of each `service`, holding your data.

To answer your question: I would argue that storing data in a `service` instead of a `controller` is always reasonable when it works (aka when the data is not specific to one of multiple views, but consistent throughout the current application state), and giving access to that data to manipulate it is perfectly fine - even better would be to put the manipulation logic into the service itself (or another service only for that) and to just let the `controller` connect to a call invoking that.

There is an [article](http://toddmotto.com/rethinking-angular-js-controllers/) by Todd Motto on that topic (thin controllers)

Comment: So if you're recommending that I store all of my data and functions in the service, what should be in the controller?

Comment: @AverageUnknown The controller should just provide the view the data in the correct form(transforming it into fitting arrays for example) and link up the views actions to business logic (or to a controller function, if it should jsut invoke some view logic like hiding something for example). I edited in a link to a good article on that concept (thin contorllers) by todd motto

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Am I correct in thinking I should create a "service-service" for my case, rather than a factory as used in your article? I'm still not entirely clear on the difference.

Comment: @AverageUnknown yep the difference is not clear to most people. The function you pass when creating a service is instantiated using the new keyword (so you are basically writing a class that angular manages as a singleton for you), while the function you pass when creating a factory just gets called, allowing for more freedom.  I would go for service-services whenever you want it to be an object that has methods, as the code for a service is more self expressing (because it kind ofmimics class-code peopleare used to)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better use events for this purpose. In your first controller you can published the event on category deletion like below.

```
  $scope.deleteCategory = function (category) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast("categoryDeleted", category); 
 }
```

Then you can observe this event in any controller like below in second controller you can listen categoryDeleted event.

```
$scope.$on("categoryDeleted", function (event, category) {
                   // do whatever you want
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not call controller directly from the service, this is a bad practice, not only in AngularJS, but in most languages frameworks.

The problem you have described ("a change in one controller to affect (different) data stored in the other") is a problem of communication between components. You can solve this issue with events, thus there is no need to move data from the second controller to the service.

Let's consider some example:
http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/XqDxG/

When you click on the LOG button the this.broadcastItem() is invoked, and the 'handleBroadcast' event is broadcasted.
Other constrollers, controllerOne and controllerTwo, handle this event:

```
$scope.$on('handleBroadcast'
```

and do the things they want to do.

So, in yor case, you can introduce the 'categoryRemoved' event, and broadcast this event in the first controller. Once the event is broadcasted, your second controller handle it and edit its items.
Also you should pass the removed category in the event (instead of 'msg' in the example), so that second controller has to aware which exactly category has been removed.

Comment: I can see how your solution would work, but is there a reason I would want to avoid putting my data in a service as in @LionC's answer, or a reason that events would be a better solution?

Answer (score -1):

In way you want to do that, $rootScope can be used (shared across controllers - modyfing in one, accessing in another), but its generally bad idea. Im not sure if I get it right but its typical situation when you actually need service with controlling some external data.. Its some static json you want to modify? Can you specify it more clearly ? :)

Comment: If it's a bad idea why suggest it when there are more scaleable and practical alternatives?

Comment: Thats why I wrote that its typical situation for having a service. But you didnt see that part, did you :)?